# Xamarin - How to call a function in Collection View without error?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, collectionview, sender

I'm trying to call a function in a Xamarin project by using the SelectionChanged property.
Inside this property, I've called a function that I've declared in the cs file.
Here is the XAML code:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="PCCollection" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="Cell_Tapped" AutomationId="{Binding Tipologia_Alimento}">
```

Here is the CS function:

```
private async void Cell_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  Console.WriteLine("Tapped");
  Console.WriteLine((sender as Cell).AutomationId.ToString());
}
```

When I click on the Collection View cell, it prints the value "Tapped" but it gives me also the Break Mode error: "The application is in break mode".

Could you help me with this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not valid. The Collection View control does not have AutomationId property.

**Sample**

```
       <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                    SelectionChanged="Cell_Tapped"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Padding="10">
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

    void Cell_Tapped(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem == null)
            return;

        string current = (e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Monkey)?.Name;
    }
```

You can find more here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I didn't understand where I can use my Automation ID in XAML Code. Please, could you explain it?

Comment: You have a list with objects right ? What type is that objects ? The AutomationId is a property in your class.

Comment: I need that every time that I click a cell of a collection view, it will give me a property of my class. In List VIew I pass it inside Automation ID and it works